# Passing session using jQuery.html5Uploader

Tags: jquery, html, file-upload, jquery-html5uploader

I am using the [jQuery.html5Uploader plugin](http://www.igloolab.com/jquery-html5-uploader/). The CMS i am using checks if a user is logged in before delivering any pages out. So i need to pass some additional parameters when uploading one or more files.

How can this be done using jQuery.html5Uploader?